# New to java 1.8.0_73 - Javac command not recognized

Tags: java

When I try to compile a .java file, it says "Command javac not found."

I've done a fresh install of Java using an installer downloaded from their website. I've tried the solution on all of the other posts that says to check my path, but it already includes "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_73\bin;" which contains which looks like a ton of utilities - except, there's no javac executable.

I searched my C drive with File Explorer, and couldn't find it anywhere. I've installed and reinstalled, so I think I might just be looking for the wrong thing to compile my programs. Please help!

Comment: Did you download a JRE?  A JRE has no compiler.  You need a JDK.

Answer (score 2):

You have installed the java **jre**.  You need to install the **jdk**.

The **jre** (java runtime environment) contains the files needed to run java.

The **jdk** (java development kit) includes the **jre** and also all the development utilities.

Go to [the download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), and select the **jdk**.

Comment: Rookie mistake x(

Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  It happens and the downloads are not always all that clear on which one you need.  If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and with jdk-8u73-windows-i586.exe from the Oracle downloads page - it installed a JRE and no JDK. Solved the issue by downloading jdk-8u74-windows-x64.exe, which installed both a JRE and a JDK.